# Location-based reminder (Android, open source)

Tags: android, open-source, gps, reminders

I want to be reminded to give back 2 dollars to Joe next time I pass near his home.
Is there an Android app for that?

Requirements:

1. Let me define an alert with a text, a latitude/longitude chosen on a map, a radius.
2. Open source, because I don't trust any proprietary app with my location information.
3. Don't consume too much power. Probably the hardest part. Recognizing Wi-Fi networks could be a workaround: I create a few "known places" (for each of these places, the app stores the list of Wi-Fi networks available at that place) and can use them later for alerts without activating the GPS.
4. Preferably using OpenStreetMap data, but other maps are OK too.

Comment: I've never tried any of them, so I cannot give a direct recommendation. But I can help you [narrow down candidates](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=129), as usual when it comes to Android apps. I don't remember having seen any OSM based reminder, nor the explicit mentioning of FOSS; but [LocationMapAlarm](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.proxy.alert) looks like coming pretty close to your requirements.

Comment: My android device has this built in, i create an alarm and the is option for location based alarm.

Comment: For point 3: I tend to turn off GPS **and** WiFi when not at home or office, but don't forget that Android can  (less accurately) determine your location through your 'phone connection .- and that is always on (except for airplane mode):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TaskNearby](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.tasknearby.yashcreations.com.tasknearby&rdid=app.tasknearby.yashcreations.com.tasknearby) may be a good option for you, because it

1. has reminders that are defined with text, a latitude/longitude chosen on a map and a radius;
2. is [open-source](https://github.com/vermayash8/TaskNearby);
3. has intelligent battery optimization;
4. uses Google Map for location picker and directions.

Answer (score 5):

Its not open source as far as I know (but its less of an issue in this case) but [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama) might work pretty well here

1. You can use the [maps add on for this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.LlamaMap%5C) I think - but Llama normally dosen't rely on maps
2. Nope, but can work independantly of any maps provider. No one gets your information. The app does not have the INTERNET permission, it can detect WiFi networks but not use them.
3. Can be trained to remember the *cell towers* and *wifi access points* in an area and uses that for location, so almost no additional battery usage
4. Uses google maps data optionally, but dosen't really need it

Comment: Sounds great, too bad it is not open source... As you know, being open source is a strong requirement.

Comment: Link is dead. Has the app been discontinued?

Answer (score 2):

There's an app from Google that comes with this functionality: [Google Keep](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.keep) - You can create a note, and set an address-based location reminder on it, from the options at the bottom of the note.

When the phone is at the set location, a notification manifests, reminding of this note. Notes/reminders can be set from https://keep.google.com/ too.

Data is stored in your Google account, and hence probably meets your security requirements too.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not open source. Open source is a strong requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: im the author of that app...

There is a free [/du:/ Tasks app](http://dutasks.com) that matches your requirements except it is not opensource. But I would put it that way:

You want opensource because you dont trust closed one.

To be able to check opensource app that it is "good" to your standards, you actually should be able to read and understand java code and specifics of Android API, thus being a software developer.

If you are a software developer (and looks like you really are :) ) you could write simple app yourself over weekend.

Comment: They are many reasons for which to consider picking open-source software. Some are moral, some are technical. In this case, the OP wishes to ensure that his data remains his, and using OSS that is monitored by many is a good way to do so, be he proficient or not with coding. Besides this, please look at our [answer quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) and edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: Checking code is MUCH faster than writing code. My weekends are already full for the next 200 years haha, and a good app for this would probably make more than a weekend to implement :-) Sorry, open source is really an imperative requirement for this question.

Comment: I think in this case, he dosen't want something that would report back his information, I do suspect google keep meets many of his criteria, but it definately reports back to google. The power usage criteria is tricky as well - llama uses a fairly clever approach there, and there's very little need for data leakage to do its thing.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I got your point, you are sayin "open source is really an imperative requirement for this question". And I do understand that I've been downvoted for my comment on "opensourceness" matter. Here is 2 answers atm and both offers closed source and both actually dont answer your question well :)

Comment: @IljaS. I am not the one who downvoted you actually. You are right, both answers are closed source, that's why I haven't accepted any yet... waiting for the perfect solution to get created :-)

Comment: @IljaS. it looks like you are new here. Sorry that you got downvoted.  But I did look at your app and it does look like it could help answer the question.  If you edit your answer to explain how your app answers the question, just like others did - addressing points 1 through 4 - then I will upvote you and I am sure that others will too. We want to have you on board and helping, so I would hate for you to get downvoted and then just leave the site.

Comment: If it does indeed take you just one weekend to write such an app, have you considered making your app open source and relying on donations to compensate your work? I would sure as hell pay a few bucks for such an app. Better yet, I may be able to contribute and make it even better.