# Android app to wake me up at my subway/train station

Tags: gratis, android, geo-location, alarm-clock, travel

I almost never sleep in the subway because I am afraid of missing my station. I could set my alarm clock, but when sleepy I am not good at calculating how long it will take to get there.

As most of the trip is underground, GPS is not a solution. If the app can get some GPS info when not underground, and use that info to improve its accuracy then that's great, but it should not rely entirely on GPS.

The app could:

- Use Android's accelerometer to count stations and recognize curves (fortunately I don't move much when sleeping).
- Analyze wireless networks and network cells to get an idea of where it is.
- Analyze train and station announcements. On some of Tokyo's lines, each station has its own short melody.

Notes:

- A period of "training" is OK.
- Waking me up early if confidence is low is OK.
- Must be free, ideally open source.

Bonus if I don't have to specify where I am now when starting.

Unlike [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/location-based-reminder-android-open-source), battery life here is not a concern, as this question is mostly for urban distances (under 20 kilometers) and short times (under 30 minutes).

Comment: [Location Alerts & Reminders](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationalert) can use different sources; one you forgot to mention are network cells. I've not tried any of them yet and thus cannot tell which one is capable of what you need (and how well it's doing its job) – but my list should at least give you a good starting point while waiting for answers. Hint: FOSS apps usually go along with an IzzyOnDroid or F-Droid icon in that list :)

Comment: PS: I'm just walking my own list to point out what location sources are used. Only few apps mention that explicitly, but most request permission to access GPS and network location. An especially promising candidate seems [Road Rooster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dextr.roadroosterpro), which explicitly states using "fused location" (ie. GPS, network, WiFi and whatever else is available).